# R: Oxforddown numbers all my lines in pdf... What is the issue?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am preparing my master dissertation and took the challenge of doing it all in R together with 2 students.

I used the template from Ulrik Lyngs. Modified the index.Rmd. But now all my lines are numbered...

[image]

See infra for index.Rmd code.
What I had to do to make it work (build the thesis), is download MacTex and uninstall tinyTex. But I really don't know what went wrong.

````
---
#####################
## thesis metadata ##
#####################
title: |
  Thesis title 
author: Faes, E. 
college: Master in Finance
university: Antwerp Management School
university-logo: templates/beltcrest.pdf
submitted-text: A thesis submitted for the degree of
degree: Master in Finance
degreedate: June 2021
abstract: |
  `r paste(readLines("front-and-back-matter/_abstract.Rmd"), collapse = '\n  ')`
acknowledgements: |
  `r paste(readLines("front-and-back-matter/_acknowledgements.Rmd"), collapse = '\n  ')`
dedication: For Yihui Xie
abbreviations: "front-and-back-matter/abbreviations" # path to .tex file with abbreviations

#######################
## bibliography path ##
#######################
bibliography: references.bib

########################
## PDF layout options ###
#########################
masters-submission: false
corrections: false # correction highlighting 

## binding / margins ##
page-layout: twoside #'nobind' for equal margins (PDF output), 'twoside' for two-sided binding (mirror margins and blank pages), leave blank for one-sided binding (left margin > right margin)

## position of page numbers ##
ordinary-page-number-foot-or-head: foot #'foot' puts page number in footer, 'head' in header
ordinary-page-number-position: C  #C = center, R = right, L = left. If page layout is 'twoside', O = odd pages and E = even pages. E.g. RO,LE puts the page number to the right on odd pages and left on even pages
chapter-page-number-foot-or-head: foot #you may want it to be different on the chapter pages
chapter-page-number-position: C

## position of running header ##
running-header: true #indicate current chapter/section in header?
running-header-foot-or-head: head
running-header-position-leftmark: LO #marks the chapter. If layout is 'nobind', only this is used.
running-header-position-rightmark: RE  #marks the section.

draft-mark: false # add a DRAFT mark?
draft-mark-foot-or-head: foot ##'foot' = in footer, 'head' = in header
draft-mark-position: C

## section numbering ##
section-numbering-depth: 2 # to which depth should headings be numbered?

## tables of content ##
toc-depth: 2 # to which depth should headings be included in table of contents?
lof: true # include list of figures in front matter?
lot: true # include list of tables in front matter?
mini-toc: false  # include mini-table of contents at start of each chapter? (this just prepares it; you must also add \minitoc after the chapter titles)
mini-lot: false  # include mini-list of tables by start of each chapter?
mini-lof: false  # include mini-list of figures by start of each chapter?

## code block spacing ##
space-before-code-block: 10pt
space-after-code-block: 8pt

## linespacing ##
linespacing: 22pt plus2pt # 22pt is official for submission & library copies
frontmatter-linespacing: 17pt plus1pt minus1pt #spacing in roman-numbered pages (acknowledgments, table of contents, etc.)

### other stuff ###
abstractseparate: false  # include front page w/ abstract for examination schools?
hidelinks: true # false to highlight clickable links with a colored border
includeline-num: true

### citation and bibliography style ###
bibliography-heading-in-pdf: Works Cited

# biblatex options #
# unless you run into 'biber' error messages, use natbib as it lets you customise your bibliography directly
use-biblatex: true
bib-latex-options: "style=authoryear, sorting=nyt, backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, useprefix, doi=true, isbn=false, uniquename=false" #for science, you might want style=numeric-comp, sorting=none for numerical in-text citation with references in order of appearance

# natbib options #
# natbib runs into fewer errors than biblatex, but to customise your bibliography you need to fiddle with .bst files
use-natbib: false # to use natbib, set this to true, and change "output:bookdown::pdf_book:citation_package:" to "natbib"
natbib-citation-style: authoryear #for science, you might want numbers,square
natbib-bibliography-style: ACM-Reference-Format #or plainnat or some .bst file you download

#####################
## output options  ##
#####################
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    citation_package: biblatex
    template: templates/template.tex
    keep_tex: true
    #pandoc_args: "--lua-filter=scripts_and_filters/colour_and_highlight.lua"
  bookdown::bs4_book: 
    css: 
      - templates/bs4_style.css
      - templates/corrections.css # remove to stop highlighting corrections
    theme:
      primary: "#6D1919"
    repo: https://github.com/ulyngs/oxforddown
    #pandoc_args: "--lua-filter=scripts_and_filters/colour_and_highlight.lua"
  bookdown::gitbook:
    css: templates/style.css
    config:
      sharing:
        facebook: false
        twitter: yes
        all: false
  bookdown::word_document2:
    toc: true   
link-citations: true
documentclass: book
always_allow_html: true #this allows html stuff in word (.docx) output
# The lines below make the 'knit' button render the whole thesis to PDF, HTML, or Word
# When outputting to PDF, you can clean up the files LaTeX generates by running 
# 'file.remove(list.files(pattern = "*.(log|mtc|maf|aux|bbl|blg|xml)"))' in the R console
knit: (function(input, ...) {bookdown::render_book(input, output_format = "bookdown::pdf_book")})
#knit: (function(input, ...) {bookdown::render_book(input, output_format = "bookdown::bs4_book")})
#knit: (function(input, ...) {bookdown::render_book(input, output_format = "bookdown::gitbook")})
#knit: (function(input, ...) {bookdown::render_book(input, output_format = "bookdown::word_document2")})
---


```{r install_packages, include=FALSE}
source('scripts_and_filters/install_packages_if_missing.R')
```

```{r create_chunk_options, include=FALSE, eval=knitr::is_latex_output()}
source('scripts_and_filters/create_chunk_options.R')
source('scripts_and_filters/wrap_lines.R')
```

<!--
Include the create_chunk_options chunk above at the top of your index.Rmd file
This will include code to create additional chunk options (e.g. for adding author references to savequotes)
and to make sure lines in code soft wrap
If you need to create your own additional chunk options, edit the file scripts/create_chunk_options.R
-->

<!-- This chunk includes the front page content in HTML output -->
```{r ebook-welcome, child = 'front-and-back-matter/_welcome-ebook.Rmd', eval=knitr::is_html_output()}
```
````

Comment: http://phoenix.yizimg.com/ulyngs/oxforddown for the repo I used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbered lines are very nice for reviewers. You don't want them in the final submitted version of the thesis, but it's nice for a reviewer to be able to say "You repeated the word Thanks on line 13", instead of making them count lines themselves.

To turn them on, keep

```
includeline-num: true
```

in your YAML.  To turn them off, set this to `false`.